# Cannot assign to read only property 'property' of object '#<Object>'

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface, instance, readonly

I have this problem.

With interface:

```
export interface IDevice {
  id: string,
  selected: boolean
}
```

creating instance by:

```
let newDevice: IDevice = {
  id: uuid4(),
  selected: false,
} as IDevice;
```

It gets added to array in recoil state, and in React used in a function where array has been retrieved with useRecoilState().
`const [leftList, setLeftList] = React.useState<IDevice[]>([]);`

Now it is being used in a handler for selecting the devices on a list control, here the error occurs:

```
...
leftList.map((item: IDevice) => {     
      if (item.id === event.dataItem.id) {
        item.selected = !item.selected;
      }
      return item;
    })
...
```

And I get the error: Cannot assign to read only property 'selected' of object '#'

Even cloning the array first by [...leftList] does not help.

I'm lost:-) Hope someone can spread light on this?

Comment: State shouldn't be modified directly, which is what TS is trying to tell you by making your object read-only, create a new object and return that instead `return {...item, selected: item.id === event.dataItem.id ? !item.selected : item.selected}`. Cloning the array using the spread syntax will only do a shallow copy, and won't do a deep-copy of the objects within it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

State shouldn't be modified directly, which is what you're currently doing now in your `.map()` method by updating the objects. TS is trying to tell you not to do this by making your objects read-only.

Instead, you can create a new object with all the properties from `item` (done using the [spread syntax ...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)), along with a new overwritting property `selected`, which will use the negated version of the item's currently selected item if the id matches the event's data item id, or it'll keep the original selected value:

```
leftList.map((item: IDevice) => ({
  ...item, 
  selected: item.id === event.dataItem.id ? !item.selected : item.selected
}))
```

Cloning the array using the spread syntax (`[...leftList]`) will only do a shallow copy, and won't do a deep-copy of the objects within it, as a result, modifying the object references within `.map()` is still modifying the original state.

Or, instead of spreading the `item` object and creating a new object each time (which can hinder performance a little as pointed out by [@3limin4t0r](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3982562/3limin4t0r)), you can instead only return a newly created object when you want to modify the `selected` property:

```
leftList.map((item: IDevice) => {     
  if (item.id !== event.dataItem.id) return item;
  return {...item, selected: !item.selected};
});
```

Comment: Note that this solution isn't the best for performance since you create a new object for each element within the array, even if that element does not change. You could add a guard clause to resolve this `if (item.id !== event.dataItem.id) return item` then create the copy with changes below that.